# How to apply multiple criteria when using VLOOKUP+QUERY+IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

So, right now, the formula below successfully queries data from another file, butthis based on a column's data as the criteria. The need is to have more than one criteria and I'm not sure if thecolumn to be compared against needs to come in as an additional query, together with the first query...so I'm lost here.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=Arrayformula(
   if(F9:F="";"";
      vlookup(A9:A;
         QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxXXXXXXXxxxxxXXXX/edit";"Costura!A1:R"); 
         "select Col6, Col8, Col14";0)
      ;2;0)
    )
 )
```

Here's a [sample file with dummy data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)!

Comment: Do you need multiple IMPORTRANGE? You can do it with
=QUERY({
    IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "'sheetname1'!A1:B10");
    IMPORTRANGE("URL2", "'sheetname2'!A1:B10");
    IMPORTRANGE("URL3", "'sheetname3'!A1:B10");
  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be done like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B6:B="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A6:A&B6:B, 
 {QUERY(Data!A1:J, "select A", 0)&
  QUERY(Data!A1:J, "select H", 0), 
  QUERY(Data!A1:J, "select J", 0)}, 2, 0))))
```

which will translate into this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B6:B="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A6:A&B6:B, 
 {IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Data!A:A")&
  IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Data!H:H"), 
  IMPORTRANGE("1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Data!J:J")}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Why would this on give this ```VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.``` error?
```=Arrayformula(if(F9:F="";;IFNA(vlookup(A9:A&F9:F&"Expedição";
{IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Costura!F2:F")&
IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Costura!H2:H")&
IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Costura!R2:R");
IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Costura!N2:N")};2;0))))```

Comment: @santosOnit should be: `=Arrayformula(if(F9:F="";;IFNA(vlookup(A9:A&F9:F&"Expedição"; {IMPORTRANGE("xx";"Costura!F2:F")& IMPORTRANGE("xx";"Costura!H2:H")& IMPORTRANGE("xx";"Costura!R2:R")\ IMPORTRANGE("xx";"Costura!N2:N")};2;0))))` also dont forget to run standalone IMPORTRANGE formula first to connect your sheets

Comment: WHAT!?!? I even thought that the ```\``` was a typo. Worked nicely! Thank YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For a system like this, the best practice is just to import the entirety of the imported data in a tab of it's own, then run a vlookup to that tab using "both" criteria.  This will simplify your formulas and also does not increase processing time at all.  Just hide the "naked" import tab.

I will demonstrate on your sample sheet in two tabs beginning with "MK".

but the basic idea is an ampersanded (&'ed) [search key] in your VLOOKUP()

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6:A&B6:B,{MK_Data!A:A&MK_Data!H:H,MK_Data!J:J},2,0)))
```

Comment: Hi, Matt! Thanks a lot. I guess that considering the main business requirement is that other users don't have access to more data and that the queried dataset is not going to be that large, I'll stick to processing it on the fly instead of bringing it in. I definitely have other situations where I'll pick this approach, though! Thank you!"

Comment: THe idea is that you would both "protect" and "Hide" that tab.  Users would not be able to see it. @santosOnit

Comment: True! Hadn't tested this protected hidden sheet yet! Thank you!